# assigning to the base part of a derived class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm looking for a way to assign to the base part of a derived class from a variable of the base class, without having to explicitly assign each assignable property one by one. Put another way: starting from a variable of the base class, I'd like to end up with a variable of the derived class that has all of the assignable base properties set, without having to remember what they are, or edit code if they change.

I create view models as derived classes from the base class of an Entity that's about to be edited. Usually this is just to add the IDs for navigation properties so they can be returned by the POST. For example:

```
public class ThingEditView : Thing
{
    public int UsefulID { get; set; }
}
```

It gets used like this:

```
var foo = new ThingEditView
{
    UsefulID = thisThing.Useful.ID,
    A = thisThing.A,
    B = thisThing.B,
    /* and potentially many more properties from the base class Thing */
};
return View(foo);
```

But, I run into trouble when I add properties to the base class `Thing` and forget to edit all the places where I initialize a `ThingEditView` or a `ThingDetailView`, etc. I would love to be able to say

```
var foo = new ThingEditView
{
    base = thisThing,
    UsefulID = thisThing.Useful.ID
};
```

and let the compiler figure out which fields to assign. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for insight!

Comment: Maybe [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) can help you.

Comment: Agreed, something like Automapper is the only way

Comment: Thanks Andre (bedanke mich) and Eric. AutoMapper seems a bit heavier than I wanted, though maybe it's exactly what I need. Odd that there isn't a way to say this in C# directly. In C days I would be reaching for `memcpy(... sizeof(Thing))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void Main()
{   
    var thisThing= new ThingEditView {UsefulID = 1, A = 2, B = 3};
    var foo = new ThingEditView(thisThing);

    //foo.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Thing
{
    public int A {get; set;}
    public int B {get; set;}        
    public Thing() {}
    public Thing(Thing thing)
    {    
     this.A = thing.A;
     this.B = thing.B;
    }
}

public class ThingEditView : Thing
{
    public int UsefulID {get; set;}
    public ThingEditView() {}
    public ThingEditView(Thing thing) : base(thing) {

    }
    public ThingEditView(ThingEditView view) : base(view) {
        this.UsefulID = view.UsefulID;
    }
}
```

I would choose for an automapper.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. This is nice but it does require that the constructor for `ThingEditView` be edited to track any edits to `Thing`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. The Thing constructor is responsible to copy its own properties and helps the inheritants to call this code via base(view)

Comment: No worries... I'm the one slow on the uptake. This is *exactly* what I'm looking for. Thanks!!